# Which is the best method to show tabular data from SQL Server 2008 in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sql-server-2008

I have heard there are numerous method to show data from a SQL Server 2008 database to asp.net page.

Some of them that I heard are like:

1. Using jQuery to call web service which will throw preformed html table that can be squeezed into an html div.
2. Using data set and binding it data grid.
3. Using script manager and update panel for async data retrieval.
4. using method given on this below link
   http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs

I am starting on a big project and don't know which method to follow. Like one which is much secure and is also using ajax in some way.

Enlighten me here if you would like to suggest the best method to do so. A method which is also secure and using ajax.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Has anyone heard of JSON jTable.
Is it any good?

Answer (score 0):

If you are committed to asp.net, I would recommend looking at [this article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-JavaScript-d0d64dd7) and others by Daniel Roth and using [WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api) and [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) along with jQuery.

Comment: Thats new. What I was thinking of using update panel and script manager as mentioned on this link.
ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control